# Hide a control without leaving empty space

Tags: winforms, layout, user-controls, devexpress

I have a WinForms project based heavily on the DevExpress Windows Forms suite. I am working on a control that appears as below:

[image: Image of control question is about]

I use the term *programme* to differentiate between training programmes for people, from *program*, meaning computer program.  In the image there are 3 `ProgrammeGroup` user controls. Each has a header, with 2 combos, and below that, a `ProgrammeDetail` user control with programme details.

When the top, left combo shows a value of *Yes* or *blank*, the programme details must be visible, otherwise not. When making a `ProgrammeDetail` control invisible, I also set its `Height` to zero, and the outer `ProgrammeGroup` control shrinks on auto-size.

However, if I set the Yes/No combo on the middle `ProgrammeGroup` to *No*, that
`ProgrammeGroup` shrinks, but leaves a gap between the header only middle control and the bottom control. This gap is visible in the following image:

[image]

How can I lay my `ProgrammeGroup` controls out so that if one shrinks in height, all those below it are moved up, meaning no empty gap. I am hoping that one of the many different panels in the DevExpress WinForms suite can help me do this, but I am stumped at finding one.

Comment: Unclear to me. Could you please post picture of it not working?

Comment: @AleksaRistic I have added such an image.

Comment: Is width of that controls allways full width?

Comment: Anyway just try `FlowLayoutPanel` and see how it does for you.

Comment: @AleksaRistic Yes, width is always full and of no real concern.

Comment: Try as i said with `FlowLayoutPanel`. It arrange elements one after another automatically.

Comment: @AleksaRistic Thanks. Why not answer and I'l;l accept. You have saved me sop much trial and error time.

Comment: No problem. Okay i will. Glad that worked out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to this problem is using `FlowLayoutPanel` which automatically align controls inside it next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to adjust sizes and locations of child controls is to place them onto [LayoutControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3407/Controls-and-Libraries/Form-Layout-Managers/Layout-and-Data-Layout-Controls/Layout-Control). This control is specially designed for such tasks. To hide unnecessary layout items/groups, use the [BaseLayoutItem.Visibility](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraLayout.BaseLayoutItem.Visibility.property) property.

I should also note that LayoutControl is flexible and supports different modes including the [Flow Layout Mode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3407/Controls-and-Libraries/Form-Layout-Managers/Layout-and-Data-Layout-Controls/Layout-Control#flowlayout).

See Also:

[Customization Form](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2173/Controls-and-Libraries/Form-Layout-Managers/Layout-and-Data-Layout-Controls/Design-Time-and-Runtime-Customization/Customization-Form)